# Question: Properties of differential equation (linear, homogeneous, order, constant coefficients..)

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Hi maths people I have question for test I write next week.
There are differential equations and you say what property they have.
But my issue is I maybe don't understand all property right.

For **order** I count maximum number of derivative line. By this I mean for example $y''' + y''$ maximum line is $3$ so this is 3th order.

**Linear** you check if exponent of $y$ or $y$ with lines is equal to $1$. Example $(y'')^4$ not linear, $y^2$ not linear, but $y+y''$ is linear.

**Homogeneous** you check if equation is equal with zero and check if function have.. I call it disturbing function. If it have disturbing function you have no homogenetic. I don't can explain good sorry but here is example:

$y'''+2y'' = 0$ this is homo because equal to zero and no disturbing function.

$y'''-6xy' = 2-3e^x$ this is no homo because there is disturbung function $2$

But I have question, what if this is $y'''-6xy' = 3e^x$ (so without $2$) instead? I think is homogeneous because $x$ and $y$ belong to equation so there is no disturbing function. Is this right?

But what is **constant coefficient**? I think coefficient is the thing factorized by the variables. When it is number, it is constant coefficient. 
But I don't know.. can you please give example?

---

Here is summary I make examples (can you say if this is right?):

$y''' +2y'' -5y'+3y+2=0$, 3th order, linear, constant coefficients, no homo

$2xy+x^2y'=0$, 1st order, linear, no constant coefficients because muliply by $x$, homo

> Can you please say if all is good? My friend also not sure we learn
>   together and this is only thing we must understanded then ready for
>   test in school! Thank you very much for read all my question!!

Comment: Non-homogeneous diff. equations if and only if the RHS is non zero. Thus $y'''-6xy' = 3e^x$ is **non**-homogeneous.

Comment: $y'''-6xy' = 3e^x$ is not a homogeneous linear differential equation. Linear Homogeneous ODE are of form $$a_n y^{(n)} + ... + a_1 y' + a_0 y = 0$$, where $a_k$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: @JeanMarie So simply saying when there is $x$ somewhere in function, it must be multiplied by $y$ then it is homo. Example: $y'''-6xy' =y \cdot 3e^x$ is homogeneous?

Comment: And there are two types of homogeneous ODE. See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation.

Comment: @A---B Same question I ask Marie for you pls is this correct my comment? Thank you for all help so far I will understand :)

Comment: @Hamudii Yes it is a linear homogeneous ODE.

Comment: Yes, in this example, because when you place all elements containing an $y,y',y''...$ in the LHS, you have a zero on the RHS . Moreover, it is linear.

Comment: @JeanMarie In end of my question I make $2$ examples. Is it correct about constant coefficients?

Comment: @Hamudii Willl you call $3y'' + x y' = 0$ consant coefficient or no constant coefficient ?

Comment: @A---B  $3$ is constant coefficient but $x$ isn't because it can be anything.  So this equation is no constant coefficient. I hope this is right?

Comment: Yes your characterizations are correct for the 2 examples.

Comment: @Hamudii You are correct.

Comment: Thank you all you help me so much!!!! :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, when I first read your post as an american I thought you "writing" the test meant you were the teacher and I was scared for your class.

For order, your heuristic method is not terrible but it will mislead you in cases like this, $y'' + y' + y = y''$. This is a first order equation but there are terms with two "derivative lines" as you put it.

For linearity, you need to substitute a linear combination of solutions and show that is also a solution. What this is means is that everywhere you see $y$ you replace by $\alpha u + \beta v$ where you assume $\alpha, \beta$ are constants and $u$ and $v$ both satisfy the equation you are considering. Example: $y''+y=0$ is linear because $(\alpha u + \beta v)'' +(\alpha u + \beta v) = \alpha u'' + \beta v'' + \alpha u + \beta v= \alpha u'' + \alpha u + \beta v'' +\beta v= \alpha(u''+u)+\beta(v''+v)=\alpha\cdot0 + \beta\cdot 0=0$.

For homogeneity, you need to show that if $u$ is a solution then so is $cu$ for any constant $c$. For example, $y''+y=0$, we substitute $(cu)''+cu=cu''+cu=c(u''+u)=c\cdot0=0$.

The equation you ask about in your original post is NOT homogeneous, let's test the method described above. We substitute $cu$ into the equation to get, $(cu)''' -6x(cu)'=c(u'''-6xu)=c(3e^x)\neq 3e^x$ unless $c=1$. However, this condition must hold for ALL $c$, thus the equation is not homogeneous.

Comment: Thank you very much the formulas you all show me is better than my methods because there is cases where my dont work.  I understand all but only no understand constant coefficients. Coefficients are things we multiply in equation with $y, y''$ etc. They need to be constant. And if they are not number, they are not constant. Example we have $xy$, this is no constant coefficient because x can be anything. $2y+y'$ is constant coefficient because $2$ is constant. I understand correct? Maybe you can also check my last 2 example about constant coefficient (at end of my question)?

Comment: Yes you understand constant coefficients. Your evaluaton of the last two equations in your post is correct as well. It's not that the coefficients have to explicitly be a number, they just cannot be a variable. For example, $y''+xy=0$ is NOT an equation with constant coefficients if $x$ is a variable but $y''+cy=0$ where $c$ is constant IS an equation with constant coefficients.